# Oracle SQL Script on PHP page

Tags: php, sql, oracle

Getting zero when I run this on the php page but runs perfect in oracle sql. I suspect this is something simple at the very end of the last statement. Tried a comma and semi-colon. Any ideas would be appreciated. I don't do this often..... Thanks Phil. Edit below. Hopefully better. Appreciate your feedback.

```
 <?php
                    $database = new Connection();
                    $db = $database->openConnection();
                    $sql = "SELECT c.total,b.full,a.empty
from
(
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN depth='1' THEN to_char(nvl('36',0)*simplecount) 
WHEN depth='2' THEN to_char(nvl('52',0)*simplecount)WHEN depth='3' THEN 
to_char(nvl('68',0)*simplecount) 
WHEN depth='4' THEN to_char(nvl('84',0)*simplecount) WHEN depth='5' THEN 
to_char(nvl('110',0)*simplecount) WHEN depth='6' THEN 
to_char(nvl('116',0)*simplecount)
WHEN(depth)='7' THEN to_char(nvl('132',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='8' 
THEN to_char(nvl('148',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='9' THEN 
to_char(nvl('164',0)*simplecount) 
WHEN(depth)='10' THEN to_char(nvl('180',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='11' 
THEN to_char(nvl('196',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='12' THEN 
to_char(nvl('212',0)*simplecount) 
WHEN(depth)='13' THEN to_char(nvl('228',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='14' 
THEN to_char(nvl('244',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='15' THEN 
to_char(nvl('260',0)*simplecount)
WHEN(depth)='16' THEN to_char(nvl('276',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='17' 
THEN to_char(nvl('292',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='18' THEN 
to_char(nvl('308',0)*simplecount)
WHEN(depth)='19' THEN to_char(nvl('324',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='20' 
THEN to_char(nvl('340',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='21' THEN 
to_char(nvl('356',0)*simplecount)
WHEN(depth)='22' THEN to_char(nvl('372',0)*simplecount)
ELSE '372' END)total
FROM SIMPLE_VIEW
WHERE FACILITY='W03')c,

(
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN depth='1' THEN to_char(nvl('36',0)*simplecount) 
WHEN depth='2' THEN to_char(nvl('52',0)*simplecount)WHEN depth='3' THEN 
to_char(nvl('68',0)*simplecount) 
WHEN depth='4' THEN to_char(nvl('84',0)*simplecount) WHEN depth='5' THEN 
to_char(nvl('110',0)*simplecount) WHEN depth='6' THEN 
to_char(nvl('116',0)*simplecount)
WHEN(depth)='7' THEN to_char(nvl('132',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='8' 
THEN to_char(nvl('148',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='9' THEN 
to_char(nvl('164',0)*simplecount) 
WHEN(depth)='10' THEN to_char(nvl('180',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='11' 
THEN to_char(nvl('196',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='12' THEN 
to_char(nvl('212',0)*simplecount) 
WHEN(depth)='13' THEN to_char(nvl('228',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='14' 
THEN to_char(nvl('244',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='15' THEN 
to_char(nvl('260',0)*simplecount)
WHEN(depth)='16' THEN to_char(nvl('276',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='17' 
THEN to_char(nvl('292',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='18' THEN 
to_char(nvl('308',0)*simplecount)
WHEN(depth)='19' THEN to_char(nvl('324',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='20' 
THEN to_char(nvl('340',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='21' THEN 
to_char(nvl('356',0)*simplecount)
WHEN(depth)='22' THEN to_char(nvl('372',0)*simplecount)
ELSE '372' END)full
FROM SIMPLE_VIEW
WHERE FACILITY='W03'
AND nullcount='0')b,

(
Select SUM(CASE WHEN depth='1' THEN to_char(nvl('36',0)*simplecount) 
WHEN depth='2' THEN to_char(nvl('52',0)*simplecount)WHEN depth='3' THEN 
to_char(nvl('68',0)*simplecount) 
WHEN depth='4' THEN to_char(nvl('84',0)*simplecount) WHEN depth='5' THEN 
to_char(nvl('110',0)*simplecount) WHEN depth='6' THEN 
to_char(nvl('116',0)*simplecount)
WHEN depth='7' THEN to_char(nvl('132',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='8' 
THEN to_char(nvl('148',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='9' THEN 
to_char(nvl('164',0)*simplecount) 
WHEN(depth)='10' THEN to_char(nvl('180',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='11' 
THEN to_char(nvl('196',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='12' THEN 
to_char(nvl('212',0)*simplecount) 
WHEN(depth)='13' THEN to_char(nvl('228',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='14' 
THEN to_char(nvl('244',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='15' THEN 
to_char(nvl('260',0)*simplecount)
WHEN(depth)='16' THEN to_char(nvl('276',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='17' 
THEN to_char(nvl('292',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='18' THEN 
to_char(nvl('308',0)*simplecount)
WHEN(depth)='19' THEN to_char(nvl('324',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='20' 
THEN to_char(nvl('340',0)*simplecount) WHEN(depth)='21' THEN 
to_char(nvl('356',0)*simplecount)
WHEN(depth)='22' THEN to_char(nvl('372',0)*simplecount)
ELSE '372' END)empty
FROM SIMPLE_VIEW
WHERE FACILITY='W03'
  AND nullcount<>'0')a;
                    ";

     $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->execute();
     $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
 foreach ($result as $row) {
                ?>
<tr class="gradeX">
<td><?=number_format($row["c.total"],0,'.',',') ?></td>
<td><?=number_format($row["b.full"],0,'.',',') ?></td>
<td><?=number_format($row["a.empty"],0,'.',',') ?></td>
</tr>
       <?php
             } 
         $database->closeConnection();
        ?>
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to format it correctly? Where is `$sql` defined? Why does your query have an `a` at the end?

Comment: @Phil The `a` is the alias for the sub-query.

Comment: Add error handling and update the question with the error you get. See the error examples in the OCI8 documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-error.php

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your query to a single sub-query using conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(mapped_depth), 0) AS total,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN nullcount = '0' THEN mapped_depth END), 0)
         AS empty,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN nullcount <> '0' THEN mapped_depth END), 0)
         AS full
FROM   (
  SELECT nullcount,
         DECODE(depth,
           1, 36,
           2, 52,
           3, 68,
           4, 84,
           5, 110,
           6, 116,
           7, 132,
           8, 148,
           9, 168,
           10, 180,
           11, 196,
           12, 212,
           13, 228,
           14, 244,
           15, 260,
           16, 276,
           17, 292,
           18, 308,
           19, 324,
           20, 340,
           21, 356,
               372
         ) * simplecount AS mapped_depth
  FROM   SIMPLE_VIEW
  WHERE  FACILITY='W03'
)
```

There are two possible causes for your issue:

- If you have just inserted the data and have not used a `COMMIT` statement to commit the data then Oracle will only make that data visible to the session where the data was inserted (note: this is only visible in that one session, if the user who preformed the insert has other session then it will not be visible from those other sessions) and when the session is closed the un-committed changes will be rolled back. To solve it, issue a `COMMIT` in the session where you performed the `INSERT`s.
- Otherwise, it may be as simple as removing the training `;` semi-colon. It is not required as part of the SQL statement but some client applications may require/allow/forbid it as a statement terminator. When you use a database driver that passes single statements then that client application will, typically, forbid you from using a trailing semi-colon.

Comment: Thank you MT0.  Love the clean coding. Giving it a test run in Oracle Developer and the above runs perfectly. Tried it in PHP and it fails. More research....

Comment: Your original question showed a trailing semi-colon after the SQL statement.  This is only needed in SQL*Plus, SQL Developer etc to tell those tools that the statement string has ended.  The semi-colon is not part of the SQL text and isn't sent to the database. The database will give an error if it sees a semicolon.  So in PHP don't use a semicolon because the end of the string is identified by the enclosing quotes.  A side comment: you may find PHP's NOWDOC syntax easier for enclosing SQL statements, see https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/php-53-quotnowdocsquot-make-sql-escaping-easier

Comment: Found the fix. Had to capitalize the naming of the fields.  Error log: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: total in  on line 608
COALESCE(SUM(depth), 0)AS TOTAL                                                                       
<td><?=number_format( $row["TOTAL"],0,'.',',') ?></td>